# No Internet on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ethernet

Connection successful but no internet on hardware set when any Linux is running. Have tested cables, router, and network interfaces. Have installed multiple distros, including the latest betas. Have upgraded bios firmware.

Realtek and Intel ethernet ports and WIFI receiver on the motherboard.
OS network settings and Router settings show that IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled and DHCP is set to automatic.

Ethernet and WIFI can be 'connected' and show as such but no internet; stopped working suddenly - All were working, until they were not.
The phone can not give a hotspot to ubuntu either. Likewise, it connects, phone sees connection, computer sees connection, tray icon says connected - but no internet.

Windows 10 was still working so I made a fresh USB installer and made a second installation of Ubuntu 20.04.   I thought maybe the drivers had gone a bit funny or configuration I don't know about might have changed.

The new installation of Ubuntu has the same problem out of the box with neither WIFI nor ethernet working. Live USB instance of Manjaro also has the same problem.

Update: I have updated to the latest BIOS for my motherboard in a hope that it might help, but of course, it didn't.

Update: I tested with a slow old laptop running Linux mint and plugged it into the ethernet cable usually used in my computer. It works fine. Internet connection. Still, No Linux installation of any kind can get internet on my hardware, but windows can.  I will next try learning how to reinstall network drivers when the system is offline; maybe it isn't understanding my hardware ...  but none of the three network systems wifi, Realtek, or intel work. It's like Network Manager isn't working with hardware, regardless of the Linux installation tried.

`ping 1.1.1.1`
`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

`ip a`:

```
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:2f:74:1a:44:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:2f:74:1a:44:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::18ba:c484:a79b:2d6c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:41:a9:b9:23:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fa60:2ecb:bd13:21a6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Following is an `ifconfig a-` from a laptop running `linuxmint` and working on the network

`ifconfig -a`:

```
        inet 192.168.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a72c:956f:ff0d:dea5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f0:76:1c:be:9f:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60  bytes 7646 (7.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65  bytes 7343 (7.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 120  bytes 9420 (9.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 120  bytes 9420 (9.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ac:e0:10:54:45:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Update: A local tech support guy here has looked into this and has suggested that there are other people having problems with Linux and ASUS ROG Strix motherboards. He offers that updating the kernel could help. So I will test by using 20.10 or looking to see what distro carries the latest kernel.  I will update you when I get the time to try it out.

Update: This was a dead end. I installed the new fedora beta and the new ubuntu beta, both of which sport kernel 5.11. Still no internet.

Comment: Can you get an internet connection from your phone on the same network? And have you tried pinging to say, 1.1.1.1?

Comment: I have internet on a set-top box, four phones, two windows machines and a chromecast in a four person house.  All working.  I will try pinging.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ip a`?

Comment: I have added outputs of requested tests as edits in the main question. Thank you for your thoughts.

For a test. I booted a Manjaro live USB and it also has the same problem. Windows continues to work fine on the same computer.  :(

Comment: You seem to have no IP address assigned both on wired interface (enp5s0) and wireless one (wlp3s0). Without IP address, obviously you can't have Internet connection. As you state that Internet on other devices is working, probably DHCP client in your system is not starting up to request IP address. Is it possible that you somehow changed the configuration on your network interfaces from DHCP to static?

Comment: The motherboard carries this as a feature. [shrugs] It has a Realtek port and an Intel port - as well as WIFI. I have been trying both in linux and tested both successfully in Windows.

Comment: network interface is set to DHCP but I will check that again anyway. All other devices on network are getting dynamic IPs allocated.  But I will check that it is not isolating this machine and allocating a static IP. -- its just that .. it doesn't matter which linux is running it won't work ...   and windows will..on this same harware   but I am going to check DHCP settings as soon as I can.  Thanks.

Comment: DHCP is definitely on. There are no static leases on network

Comment: I have now checked all cables in network to hardware and they are working normally.

Comment: Router has been continually restarted, punctuating numerous attempts to find new ways to solve the problem and experiments to try to understand what the problem is.

Comment: On your other suggestion. Yes, I have now tried static allocation in os and then pointed to those static addresses with the router.  To no avail.  I have one os installation trying to use static and the other, when booted, using dynamic settings.

Comment: Hi with this information it is still hard to pin point the exact cause of this. whether it is the hardware, the router or the os... Have you checked your netplan.yaml? as well as tried nm-connection-editor in terminal? Also has this laptop connection been used before on windows? I know you said you used another laptop but unclear if this laptop has also had functional hardware. Maybe the frequency of the router is the issue. however cable should work. Maybe try to test it by using another cable and connecting it to the windows laptop to see if the connection can be shared.

Comment: Laptop can boot windows or linux and works.  house-mate using windows successfully.  4 android, two chromecast and a set-top box use net fine. my Ubuntu has been tested on the network alone. don't think it is the router. 

I have not tried configuring netplan and will learn about it.  However, I would think that two fresh linux installations would have it set to normal settings, configuring it with the hardware on install ..  but no. my hardware works when running windows 10

Comment: I am sadly trapped in windows again for the first time since learning how to use the dial-up modem on Mandrake Linux 21 years ago.

Comment: have you looked at your dns on the laptop ? if that was maybe altered that could be the issue. However I think with these issues the first place to start looking would be in Netplan. 

And from what I understand you are saying the laptop works perfectly when in windows boot? because the point that I was making is usually modems are 4.5 ghz and I have an issue similar to this with my WiFi adaptor only picking up 2.4 ghz frequencies. try creating a hotspot with your phone quickly if it shows up then you have a similar issue.

Comment: also can we see a ifconfig -a, on the laptop that would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, I have added read-out in questions because I don't have enough characters here.

Comment: my modem offers 2.4 and 4.5 ghz which appear as seperate log ins.  I don't really care about the wifi as much.  It is the ethernet, and the fact that ethernet nor wifi work. Both connect and are not given IPs.  The laptop is an interesting comparison but it is the desktop I am having trouble with

Comment: Netplan, I have never changed, and nm-connection-editor I have never used.  I will research them more soon.  I'll keep getting back to this and updating when I get the chance. I think you understand that I have installed a second ubuntu installation on the system and it doesn't work either. Nor does a Manjaro installation ...  straight out of the box. It was working for a while after I installed the new motherboard but stopped working after a few weeks - suddenly. Windows continues to work ...  which suggests the hardware, cables and modem are all fine. No Linux system on this Desktop works.

Comment: This is a strange issue after investigating more maybe we can get more clarity I will regularly check back here. Your submask seems to be fine, unfortunately will need you to look at the your other settings. 

Maybe as a temporary method check if another flavour of linux may work to see if its the os specifically.

Hopefully you can find more clarity soon, Goodluck and have a nice day!

Comment: yeah, tried a different flavour of linux by going manjaro.  I could maybe try again with something more red hatish.  THank you so much for taking an interest in this strange problem

Comment: @poised If the problem has been solved can you post an answer? If not can you update your question with other options that have been explored?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks for your interest in this problem. I have been frequently updating the question with new data and the problem has not been fixed.

Comment: I will be trying new things as often  as possible and discovered a couple new leads in the last couple days. As soon  as I have time to follow those up I will make further updates.