# Ethernet connection not working with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

## Problem

My wifi connection works fine, but Ethernet (plugged with a USB cable) does not work. It works fine on Windows.

## What I've tried

I tried installing the `r8168` driver, reboot. But it did not help. I tried `sudo dhclient`, did not help too. I tried understanding how all these network issues are dealt with in Ubuntu, but could not manage...

## Information

From what I saw on other questions, those outputs might be useful:

#### Hardware

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 78
       serial: 00:28:f8:15:08:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.43.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 memory:dc100000-dc101fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enx9cebe808f9c6
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:08:f9:c6
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

#### `ifconfig`

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:28:f8:15:08:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.36/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 2552sec preferred_lft 2552sec
    inet6 fe80::a031:3a29:4430:c215/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: enx9cebe808f9c6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:eb:e8:08:f9:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### Netplan

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Sorry if the information is misleading or not useful, but as I mentioned earlier, I have little knowledge of what I'm doing. Again, the connection works fine on windows with the same machine, so I'm expecting a driver issue. Finally, no ethernet information appear in the "Network" settings.

Any comment or direction would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: This is question completely [duplicate as this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325954/no-internet-on-ubuntu)

Comment: They are indeed a lot of threads about this issue. Seems the drivers can be handled by multiple services which conflict. I saw the thread you mentioned and discarded it because it seems different from my situation, where the wifi is working fine but the ethernet configuration does not appear anywhere. Or at least it is from my understanding, sorry if I missed something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after spending another hour deciphering all these issues I found a solution. First, I changed `etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
managed=true
```

Credits to the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257074/ubuntu-20-04-network-issues).

The `*-network DISABLED` is due to the ethernet cable not being found, and can be corrected by editing `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`:

```
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

Credits to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906636/ethernet-adapter-was-disable-on-ubuntu-17-04/909185#909185).

A bit confused how complicated it was for a layman to fix these issues. I guess it's trivial to track down when we know how all the processes for network connections are handled by Ubuntu, but that was clearly not my case. Hope that helps though.